# Multiple operations on asynchronous stream

Tags: java, asynchronous, stream, inputstream

I'm receiving a file that I want to save to disc, this has the highest priority. But I want to "split"/"share" this stream with two other operations.

My approach has so far been to have a MainStream that can create subStreams that reads from a buffer in the MainStream.

If this is a suitable approach I need some way to determine where in the stream the subStreams are. How can I do that? 
 Or is it a better way to solve my main problem?

Comment: I suspect there is a better way, but it's not clear to me what your bottle neck is.  Is it your disk drive which is slowing you down or is it the CPU used to generate the output or the system calls you want to avoid?

Comment: Do you need to be able to read streams while the files are being updated or can you read the file contents afterwards?  What if the other consumers cannot keep up with the rate you get data for short periods?

Comment: I haven't done any measurements. But what I want to accomplish is not to write the file to disc and read it afterwards. So right now I retrieve the file and save it to disc and afterwards I carry out my operations. I want do do these operations meanwhile I save the data to disc.

Comment: Unless you know what your problem is, any solution you put in place could make it worse not better.  You have a) qualify and measure what your problem is b) create a solution to target that problem. c) retest it to ensure it has improved your issue.  Creating a solution without a problem to solve just adds complexity for no gain.

Comment: Okey. I understand what you are saying. But the problem is pretty clear for me. I don't want to read from disc when I don't need to. The data have already passed memory once and I want to read the data when it is in memory the first time.

Comment: It doesn't get removed from memory just because it is on disk.  It is pushed out of memory when you read/written enough data to push the data out of memory. e.g. say you have 32 GB and you write 4 GB to disk.  That will stay in memory forever unless you use at least 28 GB for applications and/or caching more files (or you delete the files or unmount the file system)

Comment: My point is; you appear to be re-engineering something the OS does for you already.

Answer (score 0):

If I/O is not you bottle neck, you can use multi-thread write file.

The code below is just an example:

```
/**
 * @author lichengwu
 * @version 1.0
 * @created 2013-01-08 12:11 AM
 */
public class MultiWrite {

private static final int SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

public void start() {
    final File source = new File("");
    long size = source.length();
    final File store = new File("");

    for (long position = 0; position < size; position = position + SIZE) {
        exec.execute(new WriteTask(source, store, position));
    }

}

public class WriteTask implements Runnable {

    private final File store;

    private final File source;

    private final long position;

    public WriteTask(File source, File store, long position) {
        this.store = store;
        this.position = position;
        this.source = source;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {

            RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile(source, "r");

            // lock part of store
            RandomAccessFile out = new RandomAccessFile(store, "rw");
            FileChannel channel = out.getChannel();
            FileLock lock;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    lock = channel.tryLock(position, SIZE, false);
                    break;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // deal with
                }

            }

            out.seek(position);
            in.seek(position);
            byte[] data = new byte[SIZE];
            in.read(data);
            out.write(data);
            // release
            lock.release();
            channel.close();
            out.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // deal with
        }
    }
}
}
```